# Python, Flask & Jinja - How to output query using group

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm new to Python & Flask & have a question about looping output using a group.  I have a table called Bookmarks that has a field named categoryid. On my Jinja template I want to do something like:

```
bookmark.Category.title
  bookmark.title
  bookmark.title
```

I have the data part working ok with the relationship, but I'm stumped on the template side of things.

My Bookmark model looks like:

```
class Bookmark(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'bookmarks'
id                  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
userid              = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
categoryid          = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'), nullable=False)
url                 = db.Column(db.TEXT, nullable=False)
title               = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
allow_all           = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
date_created        = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_updated        = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_deleted        = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

And my Category model looks like:

```
class Category(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'categories'
id                  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title               = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
date_created        = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_updated        = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp(), onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())
date_deleted        = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

My controller function looks like:

```
@mod_user.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    bookmarks = db.session.query(Bookmark, Category, User)\
        .join(Category)\
        .join(User, Bookmark.userid == User.id)\
        .filter((Bookmark.userid == current_user.id) | (Bookmark.allow_all == True))\
        .order_by(Category.title.asc(), Bookmark.title.asc())\
        .group_by(Category.title)\
        .all()
    return render_template(('user/home.html'), bookmarks=bookmarks)
```

What I have on the template now is:

```
    {%  for bookmark in bookmarks %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ bookmark.Bookmark.url }}" target="_new">{{ bookmark.Bookmark.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ bookmark.Bookmark.date_created }}</td>
        <td>{{ bookmark.Category.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ bookmark.User.first_name }} {{ bookmark.User.last_name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like for the bookmark.Category.title to be some sort of break or heading - but I'm lost.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For categoryid foreign key that you have created in Bookmark model, you need to make another entry in the Category model.

Add following code in your Category model -

```
class Category(db.Model):
    bookmark = db.relationship('Bookmark', backref='category', lazy='dynamic')
```